# Saving Application Navigation States in The Session Security Risk?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, session

I find that When i am developing applications its a pain in the ass to have to keep current navigation state or url / query string value while i am using different methods.

I am using the [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/%22codeigniter%22) framework and url rewriting

for example:

I utilize classes and methods via the url:

```
example.com/class/method/item_id
```

so say i use a method that loads a new view or navigation state in my app

```
example.com/class/viewpage/10
```

Now say i want to run another method on the page i just loaded. Well i can't use the same generic code that handles all the requests because running a new method will occur in place of the viewpage method.

example.com/class/newmethod

Of course there are many programming solutions to this but I have started saving my navigation states in the session rather that private variables inside the class.

```
$_SESSION['currentview']  = $this->_view;
```

Is this ok. Are there any security issues that I am not aware of or that really the purpose of the `$_SESSION`...

I am a self taught programmer so if this is dumb question i apologize in a advance.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use $_SESSION for storing the state of the navigation. The state of the navigation should be informed by the method being used. What I usually do is set the current nav state in the constructor method of the controller class.

So in your controller:

```
class Items extends APP_Controller {

  function Items(){

    $this->current_nav = 1;
  }

  function viewpage(){

    $this->load->view('page', array('current_nav' => $this->current_nav))
  }
}
```

That sets the state of your nav for all methods of that controller. Then in your view:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li <?= $current_nav == 1 ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>Nav 1</li>
  <li <?= $current_nav == 2 ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>Nav 2</li>
  <li <?= $current_nav == 3 ? 'class="active"' : '' ?>>Nav 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do something similar to this, but check to see if the target link's href starts with the current URI, and set an "active" class to all <li> tags in the path hierarchy.  It's a little more flexible, and allows me to use a base Menu class to keep track of "$current_nav" for me (and I don't have to go change all the numbers if the orders change...).